# Unable to scan a Azure SQL Database in Azure Purview

Tags: database, azure, azure-purview

I am unable to connect a my Azure SQL Database to Purview. I have already followed the steps described in all the documentation. I keep getting the following error code: Error: (5521) Permission is not sufficient to perform SQL action in database.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6WQz.png) See also the pictures below.

Does anyone happen to have an answer to this, thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue from my end and it was a successful connection by seeing the error message think you are selecting Lineage extraction (preview) if you want to enable it then you have to follow the instruction provided in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/register-scan-azure-sql-database?tabs=sql-authentication#lineagepreview) if you want to test the connection please try disabling Lineage extraction (preview)
[Lineage extraction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEJD7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Error: (5521) Permission is not sufficient to perform SQL action in database**

This error causes because of ***Azure Connections*** and ***Permission*** issue. Please follow the below steps:

> **Allow Azure Connection**

Enabling ***Azure connections*** will allow ***Microsoft Purview*** to reach and connect the server without updating the firewall itself.

***Go*** to ***Database account*** > select ***overview page*** >Select ***Security*** > ***Firewalls and virtual networks*** > Select **Yes** for ***Allow Azure services.***
You can follow this [**link.**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure#connections-from-inside-azure)

[image: Ref1]

> ***Assign Key Vault Access Policy***

Create a ***Secret*** in the ***Azure Key vault*** > ***Assign Access*** using ***Key Vault Access Policy*** > Create ***Azure Key Vaults*** connections in your ***Azure Purview*** account > Register an ***Azure SQL Database*** data source> Create a ***scan rule*** by selecting the previously created credentials.

***Follow below reference it has detail information:***

[image: ref2]

[image: ref3]

[image: ref]

**Reference:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kteh9cXkHIE

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgABjnuPMWM

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/register-scan-azure-sql-database?tabs=sql-authentication#lineagepreview

[Troubleshoot your connections in Microsoft Purview - Microsoft Purview | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/troubleshoot-connections)