# Unable to Scan Azure SQL Database with Azure Purview

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-purview

I'm not sure why I'm unable to scan a particular Azure SQL Database with Azure Purview.
This is puzzling as I'm able to scan other Azure SQL Databases

From the image I have added a new database 'encrichmentdb'.

I can scan all of the existing databases e.g curationdb, originationdb, but I don't have the permission to scan 'encrichmentdb'.

Can someone please let me know what could be causing this, as I clearly have permissions to scan the other Azure SQL Databases

[image]

The error that I get when I click on Test connection is as follows:

[image]

I have selected 'Allow Azure Services and resources to access the server
[image]

Comment: can you add the error you are facing?

Comment: Hi @PratikLad, thanks for reaching out. I have updated the question with the error that I'm getting. Basically, the error is: 'Error: (5522) Permission is not sufficient to perform SQL action in database.'

Comment: check if these similar threads [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71965740) helps you.

Comment: Hi @PratikLad, I have checked the links and I have already selected  'Allow Azure Services and resources to access the server', see updated question

Comment: I just don't understand why I can access the other database, but not this one??

Comment: just check if that user has an access on that particular database.

Comment: Hi @PratikLad, how do I do that check? I don't think its a check for user access, but more of a check on whether Purview has access. And it clearly does, because I can access the other databases

Comment: I think there might be a requirement to make some changes on the actual server itself, but not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created Microsoft Purview account and registered the source:

[image]

I tried to scan the Azure SQL server by giving required credentials I got below error:

[image]

I enable below option

[image]

I set managed identity name as SQL server admin by clicking set admin

[image]

[image]

I tried again testing the connection, it successfully tested

[image]